# How to create UUID in my Java code using JAXB to pass XSD pattern restriction

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I'm going to create `ID` field in my Java code using `UUID`. I need to create *xml* from my `Book` class and validate it based on below `XSD`.

My `XSD` looks like this

```
<xsd:complexType name="Book" >
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Publisher" type="ns:PublisherType"/>
        <xsd:element name="MessageId" type="ns:GUID"/>
        <xsd:element name="Author" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"
                 namespace="##other"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="GUID">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

My Java class looks like this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(name="Book", propOrder = {"publisher", "messageId", "author", "title"
})
@Getter
@Setter
public class Book {

    private Publisher publisher;
    private GUID messageId;    
    private String author;  
    private String title;
}
```

How should I implement my `GUID` class to return a  `UUID.randomUUID()`or any other way to pass the `XSD` ?

Comment: Is you GUId class and Book class autogenerated from your jaxb schema ?

Comment: no, that's the other way. I'm going to **write this classes (GUID, Book)** and I expect this `xsd` be generated

Comment: Why don§t you just initialize the GUID string inside the no argument constructor of the GUID ?   public GUI () { guidString = UUID.randomUUID() }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/mageddo/java-examples/blob/accffc6/jaxb/src/test/java/com/mageddo/jaxb/writeandparse/XmlValidatorTest.java#L28), basically you have to annotate the method which return the xml value with `@XmlValue`

```
public class GUID {

    private final UUID uuid;

    public GUID() {
        this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getValue(){
        return uuid.toString();
    }
}
```